# The documents on sharepoint will open in 'Read Only' mode even though i try to open in 'Edit' mode

Tags: excel-services, word, office-integration, internet-explorer, read-only

The documents on share point will open in 'Read Only' mode even though i try to open in 'Edit' mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this solution on stack overflow site, which indeed helped me to resolve a problem where I try to open a document at my workplace with Office 2010 documents on Sharepoint. The original link is also posted at the end of my post.

1. On the client computer experiencing the issue click on "RUN" then type "RegEdit".
2. go to this path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Internet`
3. Right click and create new "DWORD" entry and give it a name of "FSSHTTPOff"
4. Double click the new entry and enter 1 for the value.

Hope this helps !!

Link to the original answer : [sharepoint-opens-documents-in-read-only-mode-for-users-with-office-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164313/sharepoint-opens-documents-in-read-only-mode-for-users-with-office-2010)